# Nextcloud: list files in a shared folder using curl

Tags: curl, nextcloud

I have a link to a shared folder in nextcloud, from which I can download data using curl:

```
curl -X GET https://nextcloud.whatever.com/index.php/s/9asdFa9k6264j/download?path=myfile.csv
```

This works perfectly when I know the name `myfile.csv`. But there might be other files in that directly that I don't know about. How can I list them?

I tried the following, but it is returning an empty response with HTTP code 405:

```
curl -i -X PROPFIND 'https://nextcloud.whatever.com/index.php/s/9asdFa9k6264j/remote.php/webdav/'      -H 'Content-Type: application/xml'      -d '<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns">
          <d:prop>
            <d:getlastmodified/>
            <d:getetag/>
            <d:resourcetype/>
            <d:getcontenttype/>
            <d:getcontentlength/>
          </d:prop>
        </d:propfind>'
HTTP/2 405
```

The admin of the nextcloud instance says I have all permissions he can give me.

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

The right way to access public share information is to use the `PROPFIND` method plus the share's name as `username` and the share's password as the user's password (if any) on the public DAV endpoint.

So basically:

```
curl -X PROPFIND -u "<SHARE_ID>:" https://<HOST>/public.php/webdav/
```

Your example:

```
curl -i -X PROPFIND -u '9asdFa9k6264j:' 'https://nextcloud.whatever.com/public.php/webdav/'
```

If you omit the colon after the share's ID, you will be prompted to enter a password (can be empty).

Comment: Hmm the idea with using the share name as the username sound good, but it still does not work.

Comment: Just confirmed that with the 3 nc instances I have access to. Works on all three of them... What error do you get?

Comment: I get a 401 with Sabre DAV Exception NotAuthneticated. I tried with the share name and empty password (I can access the files via browser without password)